# FindWindowA() returns 0 and when i check the error code with GetLastError() it's also 0 (ERROR_SUCCESS)

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

This is a segment out of a dll injection code i'm writing.
I'm using `FindWindowA()`  to get a HWND to the window procces defined in `INJ_PROC_NAME`.
The problem is that the function always returns 0 and when I check the error with `GetLastError()` it also returns 0. I can't tell what's the problem because the error code doesn't give me the correct information about the error.

```
HWND Hwnd = FindWindowA(NULL, INJ_PROC_NAME);
    if (Hwnd == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Couldn't find window named \"" << INJ_PROC_NAME << "\": error-"
            << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        getchar();
        return -1;
    }
```

This is the output:

```
Couldn't find window named "notepad.exe": error-0
```

Is this a known issue? I wasn't able to find any information about it in Microsoft's documentation or in stack overflow. I just can't figure this one out...

edit:
Obviously, notepad is open when i run the program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely the error gets clobberd somewhere in `std::cout`.

Try this:

```
 if (Hwnd == NULL)
    {
        DWORD error = GetLastError();  // first thing we retrieve the error

        std::cout << "Couldn't find window named \"" << INJ_PROC_NAME << "\": error-"
            << error << std::endl;
        getchar();
        return -1;
    }
```

Saving the error number right after the failure as shown above must be done anyway.

But the true reason why `FindWindow` does not succeed is because it is not looking for the *process name*, but for the *window title* which is something like `Untitled - Notepad`.

Otherwise if `FindWindow` does not find the window, the last error is in deed not set in spite of what the the Microsoft documentation pretends.

**Conclusion**

Using `FindWindow` is probably not the best approach, you should rather enumerate processes as described [**in this Microsoft documentation**](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-ch/windows/win32/psapi/enumerating-all-processes).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion but it still gives the same output. Why whould it get clobberd in std::cout?

Comment: Note in particular, that - although the calling thread's last error code has multiple opportunities to get changed until it's uncovered - the observed behavior is to be expected: There is no window with that window name. The API returns a `nullptr`, and `GetLastError` returns `ERROR_SUCCESS` to indicate, that the return value of `FindWindow` is not the result of an error.

Comment: @IInspectable your interpretation of the MS documentation is certainly correct. But OTOH if you try to open a _file_ that does not exist (similar to trying to find a window that does not exist), then it's an error.